# How to generate confidence intervals by bootstrapping ODE optimised using MLE

Tags: optimization, ode, mle

I've produced a functional response model which is based upon an ordinary differential equation (ODE; deSolve::lsoda), with parameters estimations optimised via maximum likelihood estimations (MLE; bbmle::mle2). I'm looking to apply non-parametric bootstrapping in order to generate 95% CI's for the parameters, but don't know how to go about doing it using boot::boot function. 
I've written a function based on what I've read in other forum posts (e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63652/how-does-bootstrapping-in-r-actually-work/63657#63657?newreg=9b894635d63a4becab8cef0dfd076db8), but when I run it, I keep getting error codes.

```
library(boot)
library(doSNOW)
f = function(data, index) {
  require(deSolve)
  require(bbmle)
  data = FRmod
  index = sample(1:nrow(data), dim(data)[1], replace = TRUE)
  data.new = data[index,]
  m = mle2(minuslogl = HollII.NLLmleRR,
           start = list(a = 0.36739,
                        h = 2.32751),
           data = list(Neaten =  data.new$Neaten,
                       N0 =  data.new$N0,
                       P =  data.new$P,
                       Tt = Tt),
           method = "Nelder-Mead",
           control = list(maxit = 1000000))
  as.vector(t(rbind(coef(summary(m))[, 1:2])))
}

res = boot(data = FRmod, statistic = f, R = 2000, parallel = "snow", ncpus = 11)
```

The warning I consistently get is:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  11 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'FRmod' not found
```

But I also get

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  11 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'HollII.NLLmleRR' not found
```

When I try to change the structure of the function.
I'm looking to apply bootstrapping to a number of other functional response model types, but need to understand how to structure the function, so that I can then adapt it to other model types with fewer/more parameters.

I'm happy to provide data as well as the original functional response code if needed.

Comment: To track this down, I would recommend to run a reduced example on a single cpu core first.

Comment: Hi @tpetzoldt, thanks for the reply and apologies for the delay in my response. I subsetted the dataset I'm working with and ran the bootstrap without specifying the number of cores, but did still run the parallel = "snow" function. Took about 8 hours to run, but it did run through alright - so it appears to fail when I state how many cores I want to use......... Don't know what that means for my entire function though.

Answer (score 0):

Every core needs to get all required parts of the script. You may consider to put FRmod, HollII.NLLmleRR, and maybe some other parts in a separate .R file that is then 'source'd at the beginning of your parallelized function. As you wrote that it took 8 hours, I would again recommend to start with a simplified example.